# How do I transform a list into an equation?

Tags: python, list, math

So, I've been trying to make an advanced calculator many ways and this is the best I could think of:

```
operation = str(input('Operation:'))

operation_list = operation.split(' ')

for i in range(len(operation_list)):
    if operation_list[i] not in '+-/*':
        operation_list[i] = int(operation_list[i])

print(operation_list)
```

This code will transform every number in the str into an int and put everything in a list:

```
Operation: 10 + 10 + 10

Terminal: [10, '+', 10, '+', 10]
```

I don't know if it is possible to do that, but I want to transform that list like it was an actual equation.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "an equation"?

Comment: There's no `=` sign so this is not an equation. Can you clarify what you mean? Also, what kind of transformations do you want to do to this list or the equation you talk about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution: Use python's built-in `eval()`

```py
operation = input('Operation: ')  # input() always returns string, no need to convert
print(eval(operation))
```

```sh
Operation: 5 * 10 + 2
52
```

*Note, you may want to confirm the user entered a valid equation. Malicious users might do something like this: https://medium.com/swlh/hacking-python-applications-5d4cd541b3f1.*

Comment: The URL has a trailing `_` that causes it to 404. Can't edit because it's less than 6 characters.